# Scrape from website and save into different columns in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, scrapy

Suppose there's a website that has a list of details of some companies, for example, name, HQ area, turnover, etc. How do I scrape that data and fill it into different columns (like name, turnover) with each row having the details of a separate company?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Comment: Use `ImportXML` function, get the xpath from the website

Comment: it depends on how the web site is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets allow you to import html tables or list with the [`IMPORTHTML(url, query, index)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) function.

For example, using the Wikipedia page [List of largest companies by revenue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue) as an example.

We want the data from the main table, so the first thing that we have to do, is to know what index it occupies in the page. To do this, we can use `document.querySelectorAll('table')` or `$$('table')`, as you can see from the result, the table that we want is in the position 5 of the array, so inside our google sheet we can use:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue","table",5)
```

[image]

From here, you should change the query parameter to `list` and find what index it occupies within the page using the method described above. In any case, you could always use [`IMPORTXML(url, xpath_query)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en), and knowing the [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) of the information, you could come up with a similar solution.